# How to control mouse position on iPadOS in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, ipad, swiftui

I'm developing application which needs to control mouse position.
I want to specify mouse coordinate (x and y), and move cursor to the position.

But, I can't find any good references.
So, please tell me how to move mouse cursor to the position we specified.

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to be able to move the cursor programmatically

Comment: Thank you for considering this problem. I've tried this problem for about a week but I can't find good result. It seems that the functions for controlling mouse cursor is not a essential part for developing any Apps for smart device. That's why it's extremely difficult to implement such a functions. I'll try myself more! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Taken from Apple Documentation, the only available class is NSCursor which is available for macOS 10.0+ and Catalyst 13.2+.

[NSCursor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscursor) offers `hotSpot: NSPoint { get }`, which is immutable.

> The point describing the position of the hot spot, specified according to the cursor’s flipped coordinate system. For a more complete explanation of a cursor’s hot spot, see the class overview. Note that an NSCursor object is immutable

So the only chance is to initialize a new cursor, where you can specify a new `NSPoint` of the cursor.

```
init(image:hotSpot:) -> NSCursor object
```

> Initializes a cursor with the given image and hot spot.

Comment: Thank you for your polite explanation.

Is that a way for controlling mouse cursor in macOS, right?
I also trying it in iPadOS and iOS.
I found some ways for implementing such a function in macOS.

Do you have any ideas to implement it for iPadOS or iOS?

Answer (score 0):

With SwiftUI 2 it will be possible to capture the cursor https://developer.apple.com/wwdc20/10617